# draw charts lightweight libraries

Tags: android, graph, android-fragments

I need to draw 3 graph inside my android app. Each graph will be inside a fragment inside a viewPager layout, and each fragment will be keep in memory while app is on focus. 
Also, when user tap on a point of graph a popup with information of that point should appear.
I0ve found afreechart and achartengine libraries, but wich one is better for my purpose?
the main thing it's the lightweight memory request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another light weight graph library with much improved and simple options. The name of this library is `GraphView` library.

It provides the features of drawing graphs both statically and dynamically. Also the are many other features like pinch to zoom and others.

**Using GraphView library:**

```
Google for the GraphView.jar and place it inside your /libs folder under your applications directory.
```

Below is a sample code to draw a random curve (sine wave):

```
GraphViewSeries rndSeries=new GraphViewSeries("random curve",null,data);
                            Log.d(TAG, "Series created");
                            GraphView graphView=new LineGraphView(getApplicationContext(), "Amplitude-Time Graph     X-axis:Time(ms)     Y-axis: Amplitude");
                            Log.d(TAG, "Line GraphView created");
                            graphView.addSeries(rndSeries);
                            Log.d(TAG, "series added");
                            graphView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

                            //long xmax=preferences1.getLong("Maxx", 0);

                            graphView.setViewPort(0, 100);
                            Log.d(TAG, "port setup");
                            graphView.setScalable(true);
                            graphView.setScrollable(true);
                            graphView.computeScroll();
                            graphView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
                            graphView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                            graphView.setVerticalLabels(new String[] {"       ","    ","Amp"});
                            graphView.setHorizontalLabels(new String[] {"           ","Time (ms)"});
                            graphView.setManualYAxisBounds(300.0d, -30.0d);
                            graphView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
                            graphView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Log.d(TAG, "Obtaining reference to layout");
                            //setContentView(R.layout.graphview);
                            LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.gviewlayoutt);
                            Log.d(TAG, "reference obtd");

                            layout.addView(graphView);
                            Log.d(TAG, "graph view added to layout");
```

For using other types of graphs line line,pie etc please refer to the below link:

http://www.jjoe64.com/p/graphview-library.html

The reason i had used this library wass it is much faster than `AChartEngine`, with many additional features. Also memorywise its really good.

Hope this has helped.

Comment: @giozh: Then you can use GraphView library, as it is well documented for generating dynamic graphs. And pls accept the answer once you feel its met your requirements. -Regards.